# millis() function overflow in Tinygps library

Tags: c++, c, gps, arduino

I am making a GPS device to run for about a year without restarting. I am using `TinyGPS+` library. I noticed that there are `millis()` functions in the library. So they can overflow. Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: Can't you detect when it wraps around and handle it appropriately?

Comment: why donz you use fix_age instead, it is long, and therefore will not overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But do you need to know the time since the start of the program or just intervals.

```
unsigned long start = millis();
...
// Long running actions....
...
unsigned long stop = millis();
unsigned long interval = stop-start;
```

This will still be valid as long as the start and end are not more then 49 days apart. I doubt that you need to count the interval from start of the program until when the counter overflows.

See also here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=122413.0

Comment: Thanx uncletall for the reply. It means that millis() function overflow in nearly 50 days.
1. I doubt it will effect time intervals too ?
2. Do I have to correct all the millis() function according to the given link ? (The number is large)
3.Is it work time intervals correct even after overflow ?

Comment: 1. usless time are less than overflow value you are fine

2. yes. next time always write millis()-startTime

3. yes

Comment: Thanx @lesto. It was usefull

Comment: You may have millis() overflow between start and stop and this may give you a negative interval near to the maximum long value. This is a very rare case, but if you are controlling an atomic reactor for 50 years and can't fail it may be worth considering..

Comment: @FrancescoMM. Actually, the design is such that if you have an overflow between start and stop the number will not be negative as long as you use unsigned int. They will basically start from from 0 again. Example: start is MAX_UINT - 10, stop is 10, then stop - start = 20

Comment: exactly, uncletall is using UNSIGNED, see http://www.leonardomiliani.com/2012/come-gestire-loverflow-di-millis/?lang=en solution #2 for a more deep explanation

Comment: Thanks , I hadn't thought about that! Nice to know now. Thanks for the info page @lesto , that's very informative and clears out any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the millis() and a long int variable to count time every day, and another variable to count every day, then reset the timer but not the arduino.

With this you have not to worry about the overflow and keep working normally.